# Inserting JavaScript in a pl\sql procedure

Tags: javascript

I added a JavaScript in a oracle plsql procedure.. I have experience in plsql but not in JavaScript.

I have to wrap the code in another plsql package htp.p

```
HTP.P ('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>');
 HTP.P (
      ' <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">');
   HTP.P ('<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">');
   HTP.P ('<head>');
   HTP.P (
      '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />');
   HTP.P ('<title>Untitled Document</title>');
   HTP.P (
      '<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>');
   HTP.P ('<script type="text/javascript">');
   HTP.P ('$(document).ready(function() {' );
   HTP.P ('$(input[name="sel_crn"]).hide()');
   HTP.P ('$(document).ready(function() {');
  --- HTP.P ('('input[name="sel_crn"]' ).hide();'');

    HTP.P('  $("span.btnToggle").click(function(){');
   HTP.P('$(this).parent().parent().parent().find("tr.cDescRow").toggle()');
   HTP.P(' });');
   HTP.P(' });');
   HTP.P ('</script>');
   HTP.P ('<style type="text/css">');
   HTP.P (' <!--');
   HTP.P ('td {');
   HTP.P ('height: 30px');
   HTP.P ('}');
   HTP.P (' .cDescRow {');
   HTP.P ('display:none');
   HTP.P (' }');
   HTP.P ('.cDesc {');
   HTP.P ('margin: 5px 20px');
   HTP.P ('border: 1px solid #999');
   HTP.P ('padding: 10px');
   HTP.P ('}');

   HTP.P ('.col1 {');
   HTP.P ('width: 40px');
   HTP.P ('}');

   HTP.P ('.btnToggle {');
   HTP.P ('font-weight: bold');
   HTP.P ('width: 30px');
   HTP.P ('height: 30px');
   HTP.P ('background: #eee url("./images/collapse_30x30.png" ');
   HTP.P ('}');

   HTP.P ('.highlight {');
   HTP.P (' XXbackground: green');
   HTP.P ('background-image:url(images/collapse_alt.png');
   HTP.P ('}'); 
   END;     -- HTML - */
```

Then I added this code in another to call a precedure when a button is hit

```
class="btnToggle">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>'); ---<!-- change 5 added new cell for button -->
```

call  the pl\sql procedure  bzckschd.p_disp_listcrse.?|| and pass parameters sect_rec is the record from the cursor

```
HTP.p
                                (   ' <li><a href="bzckschd.p_disp_listcrse.?||term_in'
                                           ||sect_rec.term_code
                                         || '&p_course_subj_code='
                                          ||sect_rec.ssbsect_subj_code
                                         || '&crse_in=' 
                                         ||sect_rec.ssbsect_crse_numb
                                         || '&crn_in=' 
                                         ||sect_rec.ssbsect_crn
                                           );                               
                         HTP.p('</TR>');    


 HTP.p('</TR>');
 HTP.p('<tr>');
 HTP.p('<table>');
  HTP.p('<tr>');
   HTP.p('<td CLASS="dddefault col1"><span class="btnToggle">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>'); ---<!-- change 5 added new cell for button -->
   HTP.p('</TR>');
 HTP.p('<TR class="cDescRow">');
                         HTP.p(' <TD CLASS="dddefault">&nbsp;</TD>');
                        HTP.p(' <TD colspan="14" CLASS="dddefault cDesc">Course description appears here when someone wants to see it.  It will go away when they dont...</TD>');
                    HTP.p
                                (   ' <li><a href="bzckschd.p_disp_listcrse.?||term_in'
                                           ||sect_rec.ssbsect_term_code
                                         || '&p_course_subj_code='
                                          ||sect_rec.ssbsect_subj_code
                                         || '&crse_in=' 
                                         ||sect_rec.ssbsect_crse_numb
                                         || '&crn_in=' 
                                         ||sect_rec.ssbsect_crn
                                           );                               
                         HTP.p('</TR>');    
                         HTP.p('</table>'); --- <!-- end of new table -->
                         HTP.p('</TR>');
```

Here are my questions:

Since I added the JavaScript to the precedure, I am getting this error on the page:

```
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Set-Cookie: SESSID=QjgwME5EMjU0NzY5;
```

I comment the code (JavaScript) and recompile the precedure, and I still have error:

I can see the page in Firefox with the error on the top, but not in IE

Comment: Please see the [editing guide](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for information on how to post well-formatted code in your question. I fixed most of the formatting already.

Comment: Ok thank you, this is the first time I post here, I will keep in mind...Thanks again

Comment: What is the error message? What you ahve listed as an error message looks like HTTP headers (mime type, character set, the value of a cookie)

Comment: This is what I am getting on the page
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Set-Cookie: SESSID=QjgwME5EMjU0NzY5; when I comment the code (java script) out and recompile the procedure, I still get the error.. I can see the page with the error in firefox but I can't see in IE